# GNU marks in auto generated source by lex or bison

Tags: gnu, bison, yacc, lex

I want to submit some code that generated by lex and bison. Since there are gnu marks in them, I'm serious if it will become a trouble later to a non open source, commercial project.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lex (you are probably referring to `flex`) is [not a GNU project](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Is-flex-GNU-or-not_003f.html#Is-flex-GNU-or-not_003f), and is not GPL-licensed (it uses the permissive BSD license instead).  So there are no "gnu marks" in its output.  You may be talking about text such as

```
#line 3 "lex.yy.c"

#define  YY_INT_ALIGNED short int

/* A lexical scanner generated by flex */

#define FLEX_SCANNER
#define YY_FLEX_MAJOR_VERSION 2
#define YY_FLEX_MINOR_VERSION 5
#define YY_FLEX_SUBMINOR_VERSION 35
#if YY_FLEX_SUBMINOR_VERSION > 0
#define FLEX_BETA
#endif
```

which are conventional C-preprocessor lines, unrelated to licensing.

Bison's output is [explicitly addressed](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Conditions.html) in its licensing, and is not a problem:

> The distribution terms for Bison-generated parsers permit using the parsers in nonfree programs.

Comment: Your kind response helped me.